# AWS Glue - Avro snappy compression read error - HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, pyspark, aws-glue

After saving Avro files with snappy compression (also same error with gzip/bzip2 compression) in S3 using AWS Glue, when I try to read the data in athena using AWS Crawler, I get the following error - HIVE_CANNOT_OPEN_SPLIT: Error opening Hive split - using org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat: Not a data file. Any idea why I get this error and how to resolve this?

Comment: consider adding more information to your question .

Answer (score 2):

Thank you.

Circumvented this issue by attaching native spark avro jar file to the glue job during execution and using native spark read/write methods to write them in avro format and for the  compression setting spark.conf.set("spark.sql.avro.compression.codec","snappy") as soon as the spark session is created.

Works perfectly for me and could be read via Athena as well.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, can you share your jar file and any other help in configuring the Glue Job

Answer (score 1):

AWS Glue doesn't support writing avro with compression files even though it's not stated clearly in docs. A job succeeds but it applies compressions in a wrong way: instead of compressing file blocks it compresses entire file that is wrong and that's the reason why Athena can't query it.

There are plans to fix the issue but I don't know ETA.

It would be nice if you could contact AWS support to let them know that you are having this issue too (more customers affected - sooner fixed)

Comment: It's 2022 and this is still true. Glue Studio will happily encourage you to add compression to Avro and then Athena won't be able to read the table.